# Default UIView Animation Time Interval

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, default

What is the default animation time interval for `UIView` animations? I'm looking for a system constant similar to `UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I could get from the doc

> The default value is 0.2 seconds

read this Apple doc [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622617-setanimationduration?language=objc) for more info.